# How I find numbers with repeating digits within a range

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to find all numbers within the range `000000000..999999999` that have at least 3 or more similar digits grouped together.

Here are examples of integers that pass: `112333678`, `111234567`, `122111876`

Here are examples of integers that fail: `123456789`, `122334455`, `123123123`

I ran this line in Ruby, and then my Macbook Pro with 16 GB of RAM ran out of memory: `(000000000..999999999).to_a.select{|e| e.to_s =~ /(\d)\1+/}`

Comment: Is the task to list all of them or just to count them?

Comment: What use is there in producing an array with such a gigantic number of values, which you probably are not going to look at individually, or if you do, your other plans for the rest of your life can be buried ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it doesn't! Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

To count them, take all 9 digit numbers,

```
999999999 + 1
```

subtract the number of 9-digit numbers without consecutive similar digits,

```
- 9^9
```

and subtract the number of 9-digit numbers with one or more groups of two consecutive similar digits,

```
- (10 - 2*k) choose k * 9^(9 - k) for k=1 to 4
```

To list them lexicographically, we can use the following method:

```
Until done:
  Increment the number until done or the next increment would invalidate it
  If the third digit from the right is less than 9:
    Increment it and set the last two to the same digit
    Increment all three last digits at once until they are 999
  Increment the first digit, l, left of the the third digit 
   from the right that is less than 9
  Set the digits right of l to 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution:

- Generate all numbers from 000 to 999, and use `n % 111` to check
  whether each is a multiple of 111. If it is, set a flag to true.
- To each of these numbers, add a digit in the range 0-9, and if the number's flag was false, use `(n % 1000) % 111` to check whether the three last digits are now equal, and if so, set the flag to true.
- Repeat the previous step recursively, until you've reached 7 digits.
- Then, for each 7-digit number, if its flag is true, add the full
  range of 00-99 as the final two digits (generating a hundred 9-digit
  numbers).
- If the flag is false, use `(n % 100) % 11` the check whether the last
  two digits are equal, and if they are, add a third equal digit and
  then the range 0-9 for the last digit (generating ten 9-digit
  numbers).
- If the last two digits weren't equal, add two digits equal to the
  last digit (generating one 9-digit number).

---

Here's a simple JavaScript implementation. It's quick if you only count the results, but if you switch on the printing, it takes minutes rather than seconds for anything over 6 digits.

```js
function repeatingDigits(len) {
    for (var n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
        var flag = n % 111 ? false: true;
        add_digit(10 * n, flag, len - 3);
    }
}
function add_digit(n, flag, len) {
    for (var d = 0; d < 10; n++, d++) {
        var f = (!flag && (n % 1000) % 111 == 0) ? true : flag;
        if (len > 3) add_digit(10 * n, f, len - 1)
        else add_final(100 * n, f);
    }
}
function add_final(n, flag) {
    if (flag) {
        for (var d = 0; d < 100; n++, d++) {
            ++count; // document.write(n + " ");
        }
    }
    else if ((n % 10000) % 1100 == 0) {
        n += (n % 1000) / 10;
        for (var d = 0; d < 10; n++, d++) {
            ++count; // document.write(n + " ");
        }
    }
    else {
        n += ((n % 1000) / 100) * 11;
        ++count; // document.write(n + " ");
    }
}

var count = 0;
repeatingDigits(9);
document.write(count);
```

The number of integers with repeating groups of 3 or more digits are:

```
 3 digits:             10  
 4 digits:            190  
 5 digits:          2,800  
 6 digits:         36,910  
 7 digits:        457,390  
 8 digits:      5,448,700  
 9 digits:     63,154,810  
10 digits:    717,431,590  
11 digits:  8,025,277,600  
12 digits: 88,684,382,710
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's count how many numbers with three or more repeating digits do you have. And let's focus on combinations where "1" is repeated 3 or more times.

To calculate this number we need to consider strings with only 3, only 4, ... all 10 occurences of "1".

That is cumulative binamial probabilty whcih can be computed like this:

```
cumulative = 0;
for k = 3:10
    cumulative = cumulative + (1/10)^k*(9/10)^(10-k)*nchoosek(10,k);
end
disp(cumulative)
```

The answer is 0.0702. But in total you have 10<sup>10</sup> different numbers. So, considering only repetition of "1" you got 0.0702 * 10<sup>10</sup> numbers.

---

On your current implementation. I don't know much about Ruby, but i assume that `to_a` produces array of numbers from a range, so you asked to create array of 10<sup>10</sup> numbers. Suppose that every number takes 8 bytes ( you cant store 9,999,999,999 in 4 bytes) so you ended up with 10^10*8/1024^3 ~= 74.5 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Why not extract each digit in an array and check if any digit has 3 consecutive occurrences?

```
int number = 666455477;

int counter = 0;
//l = number of digits
int l = (int)(Math.Log10(number) + 1);
int[] array = new int[l];

//Numbers get inserted in reverse order, but doesnt matter
while (number > 0)
{
    array[counter] = number % 10;       

    if(counter > 1)
    {
        if (array[counter] == array[counter - 1] && array[counter] == array[counter - 2])
            Console.WriteLine("Number contains 3 consecutive: {0}'s", array[counter]);
    }
    number /= 10;
    counter++;
}
```

This way you can also store large numbers as string, read in each character and parse it as int into the array. If you don't want to use an array, you can simply have 3 variables storing the current and previous 2 values as well.

Not sure in which language you would like to solve, but most languages would support loops and arrays I presume.